# How to display size of each file next to it after executing the "locate" command?

Tags: size, locate

Is there anyway to display the size of each file next to it after executing the "locate" command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `locate` implementation understands the option `-0`:

```
locate -0 PATTERN | xargs -0 ls -sd
```

Otherwise:

```
locate PATTERN | xargs -I {} ls -sd
```

Of course you may want to vary the flags passed to `ls`, e.g. add `-h` to get “human-readable” sizes, add `--color=auto` to have special files in color, etc.

If some of the files in the locate database have been removed since the database was generated, `ls` will print error messages. To hide them, add `2>/dev/null` at the end of the command.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
locate apattern | xargs  du -h
```

Comment: Note that if there are matching directories, each call to `du` will traverse the whole subtree rooted at the directory. Under Linux, you may want to use `du -Sh` so that only files immediately in the directory are included.